# Linux server configuration audit tool

Tags: linux

Is there any tool that validates and checks server configuration?

I need something to audit my boxes - if they are well configured and connected to our monitoring (nagios now).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are such tools, but they are only effective if you define configuration through them. There is no magical ways for these tools to know what configuration should be considered "good" or "bad".

Standard (popular) configuration management and deployment tools:

- puppet
- chef
- salt
- ansible

However, they will not provide much use if you manually define your infrastructure. What these tools do is let you configure and maintain configuration of different machines. As I have experience with puppet, I will give an over-simplified example of how it works:

- You define your server configuration **state** using Puppet's DSL (it's own scripting language). The language lets you define the *state* the machine should be in. (Over-simplified) examples:

  - OS must have User named `user` with password `xyz` etc
  - OS must have these packages installed: `apache mysql`
  - There must be file '/etc/sudoers' with owner:group `root:root`, 440 permission
  - etc..
- You place the definitions on a master server (there are alternative configurations without master server also)
- You run puppet agent, which runes every set amount of time and checks that server's state conforms to what is defined.

Comment: This options is known to me - thanks for mentioning it. The situation is, that I need to monitor if tools as Puppet configured server in right way - I need to test it - so I was thinking about some other auditing tool to audit Puppet or should I setup second Puppet to audit configs of the first one? We are running hundreds of virtual servers and we need to know if some configuration went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For security auditing, you could use our open source Linux audit tool: [Lynis](http://cisofy.com/lynis/). This might help you discovering vulnerabilities and other issues, which then can be adjusted with a hardening script. Or with a configuration management solution as mentioned.